# Adding buttons to sub-panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am attempting to add some buttons that display information from a method I have in another class. I have already created a Jpanel and 2 sub-panels, and I am attempting to access the method from class student. Now I am attempting to create the student in the master panel, and adding the buttons in the sub-panel. Now I know it involves dot operation, but I cannot find the correct syntax for some reason.

The code if it helps:

```
Master Panel
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class myJPanel extends JPanel
{
public myJPanel ()
{
super ();
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(1,1);
setLayout(grid);
setBackground(Color.green);
student st1 = new student("Dan", "Smith", 27);
PanelLeft top = new PanelLeft();
PanelRight bottom = new PanelRight();
add(top);
add(bottom);
}
}
```

Sub-Panel 1

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class PanelLeft extends JPanel
{
public PanelLeft ()
{
super ();
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(1,1);
setLayout(grid);
setBackground(Color.pink);
JButton jb1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
add(jb1, "Center");
}
}
```

Sub Panel 2

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class PanelRight extends JPanel
{
public PanelRight ()
{
super ();
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(10,1);
setLayout(grid);
setBackground(Color.red);
JButton jb1 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb2 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb3 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb4 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb5 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb6 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb7 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb8 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb9 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
JButton jb10 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
add(jb1);
add(jb2);
add(jb3);
add(jb4);
add(jb5);
add(jb6);
add(jb7);
add(jb8);
add(jb9);
add(jb10);
}
}
```

Student Class

```
public class student 
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
int Age;
double r;
int myNumber;
student(String a, String b, int x)
{
    firstName = a;
    lastName = b;
    Age = x;
}
String getInfo()

{

    return "NAME = "+firstName+ "  "+lastName+"  "+"Age = "+ Age;
    }
String whatsUp()
{
  double r;
  int myNumber;
  String[] acts = new String[5];
  acts[0] = " is fishing";
  acts[1] = " is studying";
  acts[2] = " is running";
  acts[3] = "is interacting";
  acts[4] = "is talking";
    r = Math.random();
    myNumber = (int) (r * 5.0);
            return (acts[myNumber]);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is `st1` is undefined in `PanelRight` and `PanelLeft`.  You need to pass the reference of `student` that you want to use, for example...

```
student st1 = new student("Dan", "Smith", 27);
PanelLeft top = new PanelLeft(st1);
PanelRight bottom = new PanelRight(st1);
```

`PanelLeft`...

```
public class PanelLeft extends JPanel
{
    public PanelLeft (student st1)
    {
        //...
        JButton jb1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
```

`PanelRight`...

```
public class PanelRight extends JPanel
{
    public PanelRight (student st1)
    {
        //...
        JButton jb1 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb2 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb3 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb4 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb5 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb6 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb7 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb8 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb9 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
        JButton jb10 = new JButton(st1.whatsUp());
```

You may also wish to want to take a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), which will make it easier for people to read your code...